# Get the actual file name and extention from image file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, return-value, laravel-7

When I am uploading an image to the form and returning it from the controller, the image name and extention are changing.I am a beggar, so if I make a mistake while asking a question, I would like to apologize.

**This is my form:**

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.slider.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
    </div

    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');
        
        return $image;
}
```

**My image file name is :**`demo.jpg`

**Controller return result is like that:**

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php5E86.tmp
```

*This is the same result when I give another picture, only the last four characters are changing.*

```
C:\xampp\tmp\phpF239.tmp
```

It is very helpful to know why I am getting `.tmp` file return.

Answer (score 1):

use `getClientOriginalName` to get orginal file name

```
$request->image->getClientOriginalName()
```

To get file extension

```
$request->image->extension();
```

or

```
$name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();


$extension = $request->file('image')->extension();
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#other-uploaded-file-information

Comment: Can you tell me why the `.tmp` file is returning?

Comment: Yes, sir. this is my starting form tag `<form action="{{ route('admin.slider.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. You can also check my above code.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib try dd($request->all()); so yuo can see is file object exist in request otherwise code look good for me

Comment: Sir, After using `getClientOriginalName`, I'm getting now the actual image name.Thank you sir. But if you know the resone of getting `.tmp` Please let me know.I will be very grateful.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib this is because it i wll return temporary file name .so you can see complete file object by dd($image);